# How to Work with XML in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml

I may get my terminology wrong here, because I have never worked with APIs, XML or Web Services.  I am creating an MVC app, and a small section requires functionality to send info to a remote server, which sends an XML response.  The response looks something like:

```
<VISResponse>
<ResponseType>resultsList</ResponseType>
<Matches>1</Matches>
<SessionID>9efa7c0cc9860f108190cc8e933095cf</SessionID>
<RecStart>1</RecStart>
<ClientCode/>
<Results/>
</VISResponse>
```

I need to do stuff with that response, like display it in a view, in a form readable to the user, and I need to store the sessionId for later use.  I have been researching and found some indications of an xml class, but have yet to find a good tutorial.  Can some one direct me?

Comment: Seriously? Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx for a start, or [tag:xml]. Do you really not know how to search the Microsoft documentation?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Even better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8.aspx

Comment: There was no good tutorial out of the 6,450,000 results in google for keywords .net xml tutorial?

Comment: What kind of "remote server"? Asmx? WCF? Those have far easier ways of exchanging data than using raw XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to XML has the nicest API. Start with `XDocument.Load` or `XElement.Parse` and you'll figure out other methods you'll need to call.

You may find [this](http://www.i-think22.net/archives/2009/02/25/xml-made-easy-with-linq-to-xml/) a good start point, or this [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML).